# css - element that doesn't block the clicks-through on the site but is scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have a fixes container for notifications,

```css
#notifications_container {
/* visibility: hidden; */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0; 
max-height: 100vh;
overflow-y: scroll;
border: 1px solid red; /* only for the sake of this post*/
}
```

The container is nicely scroll-able separately from the page once content is higher than the page, but it prevents clicking buttons through it.
The problem seems to be fixable by commented `visibility: hidden;`, but it doesn't let scrolling affect the container anymore.

How could I have both? Scrolling and clicking through the container?

[Website where the problem occurred](http://nimoweb.ddns.net/playgrounds)

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbj94.jpg)

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: make the `#notifications_container` have a lower `z-index` than the content/button you want to perform an action on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: @SigurdMazanti sadly the z-index hasn't help when I made it z-index(#notifications_container) < z-index(button) < z-index(#notifications_container > div)

Comment: @Cédric I've added link to the website, source code and live demo is easily available there.